# Maven dependency provided on submodule ear throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, dependencies, classnotfoundexception, ear

Environment:

- Java 11
- JBoss 7.2
- Maven 3.5

I am getting this ERROR java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException when I try to execute a method from a class in app-commons module. Jasper dependency in app-commons is compiled and app-commons dependency in app-back is provided.

How could I solve this?

**Error**

```
09:29:24,013 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-1) net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException from [Module "deployment.accfor2.ear" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 78 more
```

Modules:

- app (pom)
- app-ear
- app-back

  - app-commons (provided)
- app-front

  - app-commons (provided)
- app-commons

  - jasperreports (compiled)
    ...

**pom.xml (app-commons)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.name.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>app-commons</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>app-commons</name>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

**ReportManager.java (app-commons)**

```
public class ReportManager {

...
    public static void addParam(Map<String, Object> params, String nom, byte[] compiledReport) throws ReportException {
        try {
            params.put(nom, SerializationUtils.deserialize(compiledReport));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ReportException("Error deserialize compiledReport.");
        }
    }
...
```

**pom.xml (app-back)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.name.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app-back</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>app-back</name>
    <description>Módul back (intranet)</description>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.name.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-commons</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
     ...
```

**ExecuteReportBean.java (app-back)**

```
public class ExecuteReportBean.java
    ...
    public void compileReport(Informe informe, Map<String, Object> parametresSend) {

        ReportManager.compilaReport(parametre.getJasperReport());//ERROR java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of transitive dependencies are not included when dependency is provided, so I had to restructure the modules this way.

Modules:

- app (pom)
- app-ear

  - jasperreports (compiled) MOVED FROM APP-COMMONS
- app-back

  - app-commons (provided)
- app-front

  - app-commons (provided)
- app-commons
  ...

I was not able to change app-commons dependency to compiled because it is dependent of app-front and app-back. In app-commons as compiled I have an @ApplicationScope class that it would produce ambiguous Beans pointing to the class in app-commons because of jakartaee context management.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the dependency as `provided`, it will *not*  be packaged into the WAR.

Either change the scope to `compile` or let the application server provide it (by e.g. putting it into a JBoss module).

Comment: I am not allowed to add library to the server and when I use compile scope I get this error with other class ERROR WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name version resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class es.caib.app.commons.utils.Version] with qualifiers [Default Any Named], Managed Bean [class es.caib.app.commons.utils.Version] with qualifiers [Default Any Named]]"}} that I did not have before ¿?

Comment: Then you probably need to make sure that the Bean names are unique.

Comment: I only have one Bean >Named >ApplicationScoped >public class Version but when I use compiled instead of provided I get this error. No idea what it is ¿? I am stuck!

Comment: You can't use `provided` if you do not provide the JAR. So no use to discuss this further.

Comment: Even if the subdependency is compiled? app-back->app-commons(provided)->jasperreport(compiled)

Comment: Yes, even then. Transitive dependencies of provided dependencies are also not included. You need to solve your Bean problem. The scopes won't help you.